# Different taskScheduler for different tasks

Tags: java, spring, spring-scheduled

I'm using Spring and I've serveral @Scheduled classes in my application:

```
@Component
public class CheckHealthTask {

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 10_000)
    public void checkHealth() {
        //stuff inside
    }
}


@Component
public class ReconnectTask {
    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 1200_000)
     public void run() {
           //stuff here
      }
}
```

I want the first task use a pool of 2 threads, while the second use a single thread. I don't want the second task is stuck because the first one use all threads available and the computation is slower than `fixedDelay` time.
Of course mine is just an example to get you the idea.

I could use a configuration class like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class TaskConfig implements SchedulingConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar taskRegistrar) {
        taskRegistrar.setScheduler(taskScheduler());
    }

    @Bean
    public Executor taskScheduler() {
        ThreadPoolTaskScheduler t = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
        t.setPoolSize(2);
        t.setThreadNamePrefix("taskScheduler - ");
        t.initialize();
        return t;
    }

}
```

I don't understand how define a different configuration for each @Scheduled component though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first task does not require a pool of 2 threads.

Different tasks do not need to be assigned different pools if all using fixed delays. The `fixedDelay` works as follows:

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay=5000)
public void doSomething() {
// something that should execute periodically
}
```

> Would be invoked every 5 seconds with a fixed delay, meaning that the period will be measured from the completion time of each preceding invocation.

Each task only uses one thread, if you have two threads, one thread will not hold up the other to be useable for the other task.

Comment: No matter how much the execution time of each task take, for every task with fixedDelay, will be created a new thread? My concern is a very slow task can block others. In other words, isn't there a thread limit for Scheduled with fixedDelay?

Comment: A new thread is not created for each run of a task. That's what the pool is for. No new threads are made past the initial amount, they get reused.

Comment: Yep, my bad. I meant: each task run in different thread. So if I've 100 tasks, at the startup Spring create 100 threads, right? So, even if a task is very slow and pass the amount defined in fixedDelay, that doesn't matter, right?

Comment: Correct, you just need to set the pool size correctly, and have a machine capable of running X threads concurrently.

Comment: Got it. I hope even if pool size > n° tasks, It's guaranteed that each task it's executed from 1 thread at each moment.